# UIInterfaceOrientation info.plist

Tags: ios, air

I am working on an iOS app using Adobe Air to package it.
I am trying to set the InterfaceOrientation to the info.plist.

So added UIInterfaceOrienation to my app.xml but it gives me "application.iPhone.InfoAdditions contains an invalid value" error when I try to create an iOS Package.

This is what the app.xml looks like

```
<iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions>
        <![CDATA[
                          ...... other values

                           <key>UIInterfaceOrientation</key>
                           <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>

                ]]>
         </InfoAdditions>
```

Not too sure what I'm missing here.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to do this via the air packager.

The closest you will be able to get imho is this

portrait
false

The solution you suggested will work in native development, but not (yet) using the air packager.

I think you are going to be able to change it via code like this: stage.setOrientation( StageOrientation.ROTATED_LEFT );

source : http://polygeek.com/4301_air-mobile_playing-with-stage-orientation-in-mobile-air-apps

Comment: Still having the same error.

But, unsure how it's meant to work now. What I wanted to do was set landscape to be 'right side up' that is with the volume buttons on top of the phone when you rotate it. The default seems to be 'upside down'.

Comment: changed my answer to something more appropriate for you situation

Comment: Worked! Thanks :)

`contextView.stage.autoOrients = false;                contextView.stage.setOrientation(StageOrientation.ROTATED_LEFT);
contextView.stage.setOrientation(StageAspectRatio.LANDSCAPE);`

Note, that a ROTATED_LEFT makes it 'right side up'